# .htaccess 301 Redirect problem

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following code in .htaccess

```
redirect 301 /movies/ /list.php?category=13
```

It works, but when go to /movies/**other.html**, it **also** redirects to list.php, but I don't actually need that, as there is another rule that handles URLs of type ^movies/(.*)\.html$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` and use the line ending `$` in your match.  Here the `/` may or may not be present.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /movies(/)?$ /list.php?category=13
```